# How to disable / enable specified Bluetooth Profiles with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, bluetooth

For security reasons I would like to establish a Bluetooth connection but only with two profiles active. HSP and HID. I am trying to write a PowerShell script but can't find any solution. any help is appreciated.

I searched for Registry Keys in

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\
```

and searched in the Device Manager.

Haven't written any code yet.

Comment: See here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/policy-csp-bluetooth - it's probably better to use a policy for this.

Comment: The BT area of the registry is HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\BTHPORT